# How to execute a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I have a WordPress option that stores some data, like:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
[shortcodesomething/]
[shortcode]Contents[/shortcode]
```

I'm displaying this option's value using `echo get_option('my_option'));`.

Of course the shortcodes doesn't work, and I'm wondering how to force them to do what they are supposed to do?

`echo do_shortcode(get_option('my_option'));` doesn't work either (I know this is an absolutely wrong approach, but I don't know any other way of displaying them).

Comment: Two things would be helpful here: (1) where are you calling do_shortcode?  On the front end?  (2) Where are you registering the shortcodes?

Comment: @Christopher Davis, yes I called do_shortcode on the front-end, the shortcodes are registered within functions.php using add_shortcode and the options textarea is in admin panel.

Comment: Same thing worked fine for me: https://gist.github.com/1338592  I suggest you make sure your shortcode callback functions are doing what you'd expect and also that you stick your `add_shortcode` calls inside a function hooked into `init`.

Comment: @Christopher Davis, could you create a new answer so I will be able to accept? But to be honest I'm not sure what to do with the code provided, all shortcodes work like they should but I can't froce them to work even with this github snippet - what's wrong?

Comment: Wait, after reseting my server do_shortcode(get_option('my_option')); works... :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as Christopher Davis mentioned - do_shortcode works fine with extra stuff included, so I decided to reset my server and `echo do_shortcode(get_option('my_option'));` started to work perfectly.

So I guess the answer has always been here, execute shortcodes with `do_shortcode`.

Comment: sometimes it's better not to think about why things seem to randomly start working?

Answer (score 0):

Store only the `Contents` (or whatever you want the shortcode to be applied to), don't store the shortcode tags in the option. Then use `get_option` to fetch these contents and apply the shortcode to it:

```
<?php
//suppose you're storing content as $op = 'Lorem Ipsum', add_option('cont', $op).
$cont = get_option('cont');
echo do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]'.$cont.'[/my_shortcode]');
?>
```

Try this. I think this'll do.

Comment: Unfortunately the option is not static, I mean, it could store really everything that user (admin) puts there, html tags, javascript code, over 200 shortcodes.

Comment: Ohh... Then you might have to use some other trick, and it won't be simply doing `do_shortcode`.

Comment: "...because the option value contains some other content as well."  That's actually wildly incorrect.  `do_shortcode` is the same function that processes the shortcode replacements for the post content and just about anything else that uses shortcodes.  It works just fine with extra stuff included.

Comment: You're right at that, I couldn't explain it well. But will 1 do_shortcode work for a couple of shortcodes spread randomly across the content?

Comment: Yes, it will work no matter where the shortcodes are.  Again: it's used to filter the content, which can have all kinds of shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you embed a shortcode in your theme:**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode option1="value1" option2="value2"]'); ?>
```

Hope this helps :)